# count days between column in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

As the title state, I have a bit problem with sql statement. I have a table as below, 3 columns : date_time_booking, date_time_use, member_ID

Date_time_booking

- 1/4/2012
- 2/4/2012 etc.

Date_time_use

- 5/4/2012
- 10/4/2012 etc.

Member_ID is Null if it is a non_member booking, not Null if it is a member

I need a query to calculate how far in advance of the booking of member and non-member of the sport center. Help/Correction/Suggestion are appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT**: This is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
   Member_ID, 
   DateDiff("d",[Date_time_to_use],[Date_time_booked]) AS Day_in_advance
FROM Court_booking
GROUP BY Member_ID
```

Comment: write the Query you have created we will modify the same and help you in generating the results.

Comment: I have edited the question with the statement I have come up with. Check them please :D

Comment: You need to add something to that. Do you want a sum of the date differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateDiff](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx) in your query.

```
SELECT DateDiff("d",[Date_time_use],[Date_time_booking]) AS Diff
FROM Table1
```

You can create a query using the query design window.

Edit re comments

```
SELECT 
   Member_ID, 
   Sum(DateDiff("d",[Date_time_to_use],[Date_time_booked])) AS Sum_Day_in_advance
FROM Court_booking
GROUP BY Member_ID
```

Comment: I have to make a report between 2 columns. I can not use a specific date.

Comment: I was referring to sample columns, not a specific date. I have changed the example to use your field (column) names.

Comment: It asked me to "enter parameter value" of Date_time_use

Comment: What is your field (column) called?

Comment: Date_Time_Booked and Date_Time_to_use

Comment: Those are the names you should use.

Comment: yeah I know I did use them,not copy and paste from your answer. I have edited the question with the statement I have come up with. Check them please :D